# Should you call base.methodName or this.methodName

Tags: c#, inheritance, syntax

If you are writing code in a class that inherits from a base class and you want to call a protected or public method on that base class, is it best (right or wrong or otherwise) to call `base.MyProtectedMethod()` or `this.MyProtectedMethod()` (in c#)?  What would the difference be? Both seem to work.

For example:

```
public class MyBase()
{
    ....

    protected void DoStuff()
    {
        // some stuff
    }

}

public class MyChildClass() : MyBase
{

    public MyNewMethod()
    {
        // do some work

        this.DoStuff();
        base.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Does this just to the same thing twice in `MyNewMethod`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does exactly the same thing in `MyNewMethod`.

I would only recommend using `base.` when it is actually required, ie: when you need to explicitly calling the base class version of a method from within an overridden method.

Comment: Note that this is only the case because the child class does not actually implement/override the method being called.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to explicitly call up the parent class? Then use `base`.

If you don't want to, use `this`.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) shows a great example on using `base`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate Reed and Kevin's answers:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class A
    {
        public virtual void Speak()
        {
            Hello();
        }
        virtual protected void Hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from A");
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            base.Hello(); //Hello from A
            this.Hello(); //Hello from B
        }

        override protected void Hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from B");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            B b = new B();
            b.Speak();
        }
    }
}
```